# View .env variables of Node.js process

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I use package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to set env variables in `.env` file. Here is the content of `.env`:

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=4000
```

Then, I run `nodemon --exec babel-node -- src/index.js` to start the project.
How to check value of `env` variables by command line?

I don't want to use `console.log` in the JS source code, I want something like so (in terminal):

```
node
> process.env
```

But it doesn't show the values I have set in `.env` file.

Could you give me some resolution?

Comment: Do you want to see you .env file?

Answer (score 0):

From your console, type following for mac/ubuntu:

```
echo $NODE_ENV
```

and following for windows:

```
 echo %NODE_ENV%
```

Comment: That code line shows the NODE_ENV global system variable. So if we run the project with param "NODE_ENV=dev" in the script, we can change the env with different scripts without NODE_ENV system variable. So "echo $NODE_ENV" will not work for this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the use of dotenv as sometimes it creates confusion that where to call the dotenv. So, you can use foreman node module and can start your project by command nf start. It will automatically load .env variables into your project without calling dotenv.